# Definite article or not in "the low sampling frequency"

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I do not mention what is the sampling frequency but I know that it is low.

**Should I use the article "the" or not in the following?**

## 1

This can be highly error prone because of narrow bandlimited channel and low sampling frequencies of their signals.

or

## 2

This can be highly error prone because of the narrow bandlimited channel and the low sampling frequencies of their signals.

Comment: If you are referring to a specific frequency use *the* .Are you sure the frequency ain't plural: *..because of low sampling frequencies in their time-frequency* ?

Comment: Is this a case where the sampling frequency is less than the Nyquist rate?

Comment: @jlovegren Good question! I will fix it there.

Comment: @jlovegren I need to get greater Nyquist rate. I think this is done by increasing the bandlimited channel and thus the maximal sampling frequency such that we follow the Nyquist theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean?

(1) "This can be highly error-prone because there is some low sampling frequency in their time-frequency picture"
or
(2) "This can be highly error-prone because the sampling frequency in their time-frequency picture is low."?

In case (1), I'd consider omitting "the", in case (2) including it. But I'd prefer a rewrite, as above.

Comment: I meant originally (2) although the original sentences were mathematically wrong already. Fixed it.